# Increase threads gradually till given time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

We have below scenario where we need to increase the load gradually till given time.

```
- 30 users per API (currently only one API)
- Add 10 user every second for the ramp-up.
- 30-second wait between iterations
- Run the test for 60 minutes
- Roughly 24,000 calls per hour (not sure on this count)
```

Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

1. `30 users per API` - configurable in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), for 1 API you will need 30 users
2. `Add 10 user every second for the ramp-up` - you need to set [ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) of 3 seconds in the Thread Group
3. `30-second wait between iterations` - Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler and configure it to pause for 30000 milliseconds:

   [image]
4. `Run the test for 60 minutes` - find the relevant Thread Group configuration below:

   [image]
5. `Roughly 24,000 calls per hour` - it depends on your application response time, if it will be too high - you can limit it using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)

Comment: HI @Dimitri, Thanks for the reply. But while doing the second step where I want to "add 10 users every second for ramp up" 30 users is getting added after 10 seconds delay rather than 10 users. I guess that is because number of threads.